# Terminal will no longer acknowledge changes that need to be made with git add

Tags: git, terminal, version-control, addition, atom-editor

This is a very specific problem so I will try to be brief but also detailed.

I am taking udacity's online free version control course and due to complications I could not work past, I restarted the course.

In doing so another complication now arose. Now when I make changes to my git repository in my code editor atom, git does not see them in the working directory as changes that could be moved to the staging index with "git add". I have added file index.html and two folders for css and js, each respectfully containing files labeled app.css and app.js.

Terminal displays the following when I run "git status",

```
 Tim (master #) new-git-project
 $ git status
 On branch master

 No commits yet

 nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

This was not an issue the last time I ran through this course, and I'm not sure why this is. Please let me know if there is further information I could provide.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` file? Are you sure your Atom editor and shell are working in the same directory? Did you save the files?

Answer (score 0):

`No commits yet` means just what it says: this is a new, empty repository with no commits.

Are the files visible in the command-line interpreter, in the directory in which you're running `git status`?  Assuming a Unix-like system, `ls` (short for "list") will show you the same files that `git add .` should see.

(It seems likely that your editor is editing files that *aren't* in this directory.)

Comment: I don't see how the directory could be different, as there is only 1 file on my computer by the name new-git-project.

Comment: You're using Atom, though. As I understand it—which could be wrong; I've never even *seen* Atom, just heard about it—Atom is one of those massive GUI editors that fires up once and you leave running forever, like a browser. In effect, it doesn't really *have* a directory in the first place. It may be saving files all over the file system, rather than where you expect.

Comment: Well that sucks. Any suggestions?

Comment: The suggestion is already there: use something like `ls` to see if the files are there. If not, poke around to find out where the heck Atom is saving them and how to tell it "no, put them over here". If it is saving them in the right place, we're back to Git itself as the problem: how come `ls` can see the files, but Git can't?